# What is the difference between revokeAccessAndDisconnect and disconnect using Google+?

Tags: android, google-plus, disconnect

I wish to find out the difference between the `revokeAccessAndDisconnect` and `disconnect` methods from the `PlusClient` object of Google+.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#revokeAccessAndDisconnect%28com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.OnAccessRevokedListener%29) it states that `revokeAccessAndDisconnect` will:

```
Revokes access given to the current application.
```

and the listener states that:

```
The PlusClient.OnAccessRevokedListener to receive a callback when the token is revoked.
```

But I noticed that even when I use the simple disconnect method I still receive a new token on each time I call the `getToken` method.

So what is the difference between those two?

If I use `revokeAccessAndDisconnect` I'm basically saying that I remove the permissions I granted my application for the chosen user?

Comment: Revoke access does just that, it revoke access to your application. Next time the user logs in, it will be presented with your G+ app's permission and he will need to accept again. Disconnect is the same as doing a logout from your app, it just closes the session.

Comment: but even if use the simple disconnect.... will it produce each time a new Token?

Comment: Everytime you send a user through auth it will generate a new token regardless of if you revoke or disconnect first.

Comment: @abraham, so if I use the connect method, resolve the choose user dialog and then performing connect again, I'm basically authenticating?

Comment: Bevare Google Plus Services 6.5. Usage is inverted, use Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is this:

When a user signs out of your application Google do not expect you to discard all the information you have on them. Just like when you sign out of a website you can always sign in again. I believe this functionality allows you to make room for supporting a user's multiple Google Accounts. This would allow a user to sign out from their one Google Account and sign back in with a different account and keep using your application. In light of this I imagine you can still keep the information necessary to allow the user to sign back in with the profile they recognize (since you can remember their details).

Alternatively, when a user disconnects their account, you are expected to clear all the information you have regarding this user on both your server and the device. In this instance the user is effectively deleting their account with you and revoking all their permissions. In this situation when they try and sign in again they should be presented with the default sign in screen "Enter Email, Password" etc.

On iOS the Google framework calls the method `didDisconnectWithError:` only after the user disconnects and not after signing out.

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627226/google-integration-ios-exc-bad-access-error-on-signout) and see Google's policies on handling [disconnection](https://developers.google.com/+/policies#deletion_rules)